# Android studio gerando dois aplicativos do mesmo jeito

Tags: android, android-studio, apk

Desenvolvi um apk, porem do final do projeto pra cá ele sempre tava emulando dois aplicativos idênticos no meu celular, mesmas funções, icones. A diferença de um pro outro é que um tem o splash e o outro não. Ai quando gerei o APK, instalei no celular e apareceu os dois aplicativos. Na desinstalação eu selecionando um apk pra desinstalar o outro também é desinstalado. Alguém já passou por isso?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="ANDROID.PERMISSION.CALL_PHONE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>


<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.MyTheme">


    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="WF Coleta">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".Splash">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".SecondActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_second"></activity>


    <activity
        android:name=".CarActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_car"></activity>

</application>
```

Comment: tentou instalar o apk finalizado em outro aparelho?

Comment: Sim, acontece a mesma coisa

Comment: é cara, pode ser um bug do Android-Studio. tentar desinstalar o Android-Studio e re-instalar, ou compilar o projeto em outra máquina.

Comment: Ja rodei em outra maquina..e nada =[

Comment: nada o que amigo? não compilou, não instalou, mesmo problema? o que aconteceu?

Comment: tente remover esse seu "final do projeto" para ver se o problema continua, se continuar, poste o código aqui para darmos uma analisada.

Comment: Compilou, porem aparece os mesmos apks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Altere seu Manifest

```
<activity
        android:name=".Splash"
        android:label="Splash">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
              android:label="WF Projetos">
    </activity>
```

O projeto só pode ter uma `action.MAIN` e `category.LAUNCHER`.

Comment: Funcionou Igor, mto obgado cara